# Angular JS - Get element height in directive before view render

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm pretty new to angular, so any help would be highly appreciated.
I'm trying to vertical align a div according to screen size (minus the header and footer) on page load, window resize and another custom event (when the user clicks to expend content). so I wrote a directive for it, I'm not sure if this is the right approach. I need to get the element height inside the directive in order for it to work.

Just CSS, without any JS, wont work in my case, the markup is to nested/complicated.. I tried different methods (inline-block/translate/etc..)

Problems:

1. the element height is 0 (zero) when trying to get inside the directive at first, I'm guessing it's because the view hasn't render yet. If this is the case, that's off course make sense, but how do I get around it so when the view transition start I already made all the necessary CSS changes via JS?
2. How to I "call" the directive,lets say, after I load more content or any other DOM manipulation?

my code so far:

```
app.directive('valign', ['$window', function ($window) {
    return {
        link: function ($scope, $element) {
            var window = angular.element($window);
            $scope.setHeight = function () {
                var contentHeight = window.height() - $('#header').outerHeight(true) - $('#footer').outerHeight(true);
                // Here I want to get the $element height so I can set the proper margin for it, for example
            };
            $scope.setHeight();
            window.bind('resize', function () {
                $scope.setHeight();
                $scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: you do not have a `$` sign in your link function

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of $timeout like this:

```
app.directive('valign', ['$window', '$timeout', function ($window, $timeout) {
    return {
        link: function ($scope, $element) {
            var window = angular.element($window);
            $scope.setHeight = function () {
                var contentHeight = window.height() - $('#header').outerHeight(true) - $('#footer').outerHeight(true);
                // Here I want to get the $element height so I can set the proper margin for it, for example
            };
            $timeout($scope.setHeight, 500, true);
            window.bind('resize', function () {
                $scope.setHeight();
                $scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Basically, what we're doing is to trigger the setHeight function after a delay of 500 ms during which we hope the directive to render. We can increase/decrease the time based on individual requirements.

Comment: Hi, this doesn't work - $timeout($scope.setHeight, 0); the timeout solution works only after 800ms, but than it's too late and than the margin css create a "jump" in the content, since it's after the transition started :(

Comment: I'd suggest that you do your full initialization/setting in the $timeout. If it's already done then re-run the thing. Of course, I don't know what exactly you're trying to do so can't help you much :(

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your call to $scope.setHeight() in a $timeout call.

In essence $timeout without a delay will happen after your DOM has loaded and so the values will be ready to use.

Comment: Hi, this doesn't work - $timeout($scope.setHeight, 0); the timeout solution works only after 800ms, but than it's too late and than the margin css create a "jump" in the content, since it's after the transition started :(

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I used **Andy Lewis & Sidharth Panwar** suggestion and warped my my function call in $timeout with 0ms that insures that the function runs after DOM is ready + I changed the markup so the valign directive would be INSIDE and ng-view (ui-view in my case), that made the changes apply BEFORE the view enter transition.

Final code is:

```
app.directive('valign', ['$window', '$timeout', function ($window, $timeout) {
    return {
        link: function ($scope, $element) {
            var window = angular.element($window);
            $scope.setHeight = function () {
                var contentHeight = window.height() - $('#header').outerHeight(true) - $('#footer').outerHeight(true);
                $element.css('margin-top',(contentHeight - $element.outerHeight(true)) /2);
            };
            $timeout($scope.setHeight, 0);
            window.bind('resize', function () {
                $scope.setHeight();
                $scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

and markup:

```
<div  ui-view>
    <div valign></div>
</div>
```