# Angular cannot get rendered paragraph's height

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to do a show more/less directive based on no of lines in the paragraph. I am unable to get the exact height rendered by the paragraph.

How to get that?

```
app.directive('moreLess', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            mlText: '@'
        },
        template:"<span>{{mlText}}</span>",
        compile: function(elem, attributes){

            return {
                post: function(scope, elem, attributes, controller, transcludeFn){
                    var lineHeight = elem.css('lineHeight');
                    //var lines = elem[0].height;
                    console.log(elem[0].offsetHeight);
                    console.log(elem[0].scrollHeight );
                    console.log(elem[0].parentNode.scrollHeight );
                    console.log(elem.css('height'));
                }
            }
        },
        controller: function($scope){

        }
    }
})
```

Comment: may be another way to do same by using number of characters, so if its more then show "more" option.

Comment: or u can check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31157184/angular-js-get-element-height-in-directive-before-view-render